# Is the function reduce, an example of dereferencing?

Tags: javascript, pointers, dereference

I read an explanation of dereference and am thinking if there are examples in languages other than C. I thought of reducing an object in javascript, where the value of one key is set to the value of a new key. Is this a correct example of dereferencing?

Comment: No, JS has no pointers that can be explicitly dereferenced, and a "reduce" operation certainly isn't an example of that. You could look at the Go language for dereferencing examples in an easy, non-C language. https://play.golang.org/p/oiXkCnTXyp

Comment: Thank you @squint for making that. I found it helpful.